# Have you been learning French since you were a kid? ---> in the past

Tags: past-simple, perfect-constructions, past-continuous, since

If the person you're talking about or your interlocutor is alive and still learning a language, you can say:

- **Have** you **been learning** French **since** you were a kid?
- My brother **has been learning** Italian **since** he was seven.

but when the person is dead or just isn't learning anymore, what do you say (**about the very same action**)?

- **Did** you **learn** French **from** when you were a kid?
- My brother **learned** Italian **from** when he was seven / **from** the age of seven.

Do these past simple options work? Or maybe, the past continuous makes more sense?

- **Were** you **learning** French **from** when you were a kid?
- My brother **was learning** Italian **from** when he was seven / **from** the age of seven.

I just want to state the simple fact that this process took place in the past starting from a specific point, and without any unnecessary point of reference.

Comment: Had you been learning since  ... or Had he been learning  since ...

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice thanks for this possibility! Doesn't the past perfect continuous have to connect to some specific point in the past? I mean in my context, there's no point of reference. Isn't the past continuous a better option?

Comment: If you are going to use a "since" construction  it will be the present perfect "My brother has been learning Italian since he was a kid" if you don't supply a temporal context, as otherwise it defaults to the "now" of the utterance.. But if you want to cast the learning in a past perfect tense, you will need to supply a temporal context to justify it: "*When my brother went to Italy in his third year at university*, he did quite well because he **had been learning** Italian since he was seven".

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice the point is that I don't want to bring the unnecessary point of reference, such as "When my brother went to Italy...". I just want to state the simple fact that this **process** took place in the past **starting** from a specific point, like here "My brother **was learning** Italian **from** the age of seven". It's like "My brother has **been learning** Italian **since** he was seven" but in the past and without any unnecessary point of reference.

Comment: If you don't provide a temporal context to justify the past tense it is marginal at best. This sentence says "I am not a native speaker": "My brother was learning Italian from the age of seven" .  It is idiomatic only if the conversation in which it occurred was already focused on some period of time in the past, to provide an implicit temporal context.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice _"... to justify the past tense ..."._ Do you mean any past tense or precisely the past continuous? Phil1008 suggested (below) two past simple sentences as possible options _**"Did** you **start** learning French when you were a kid?"_ and _"My brother **started** learning Italian when he was seven"._

Comment: Your question title used the word "since" and your first two sentences in the question proper deal with "since" and the present perfect. So one assumes you are interested in tenses that work with **since**.   Phil1008's sentences are grammatical but don't deal with the issue of "since".

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice no, my question wasn't about since. Since just means from a point in the past until now. My question was actually asked to find out how to talk about this idea in the past, how to merely state a simple fact that this process took place in the past starting from a specific point, like here "My brother **was learning** Italian **from** the age of seven". It's like "My brother has **been learning** Italian **since** he was seven" **but in the past** and **without** any unnecessary point of reference.

Comment: Learning is a process We can speak of when it began:  "My brother (**started to learn | started learning**) Italian when he was seven". Or we can speak of it in-progress: "What was your brother doing in Pisa?" -- He was learning Italian."  We can speak of your brother as a precocious learner: "My brother was learning Italian at the age of three." But as soon as the passage of time and time relationships enter the picture, things get more complicated.

Comment: When the process began in the past, and you want to speak of it *from the vantage point of another time in the past* (one that is closer to the present) the situation calls for the past perfect.  The reference to that more recent time can be made in the sentence itself:   "*By the time he went to university*, my brother **had been learning** Italian for more than ten years". Or it can be implicit in the conversational context.    "Yeah, *by then*, my brother had been learning Italian for over ten years."

Comment: You're asking for an impossibility -- how to express the idea of "learning **since** he was seven" that doesn't use a phrase similar to "since" and without an implicit or explicit reference to a later time.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice thanks for your explanations. But I'm not quite sure what you mean by "an impossibility". As I've already said all I want is to merely state a simple fact that this process of learning took place in the past, starting from a specific point. As I understand now, the problem is in the continuous aspect, but when we use the past simple, it clashes with the telic meaning of the verb "learn". Maybe, we should just then use the past simple with "study"? Yeah, it's a different verb but I know it's atelic in English. My options are below:

Comment: Did you **study** French from when you were a kid? (1)
My brother **studied** Italian from when he was seven / from the age of seven. (2)

-- (talking about a process of learning/studying that began at a certain point and went on for(over?) an unspecified period of past time and ceased in the past)

Comment: "My brother studied Italian from the age of seven" refers to when the process **began**. "from the age of seven". The prepositional phrase does entail the notion that the learning continued for an unspecified time but the sentence is silent with respect to how long it continued, and silent with respect to whether it stopped at some point (perhaps at age 11 he switched to French) or whether he is still learning Italian.  But please pay attention to this:  When you pose it in the form of a question, the time reference becomes the "now" of the utterance, and your suggestions are unidiomatic.

Comment: "Were you studying Italian from when you were a kid?" is unidiomatic unless you are referring to some point in time in the past, perhaps when the person entered university.

Comment: And even then it is somewhat marginal. **Had you been studying** would be much more idiomatic.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice You said _"The prepositional phrase does entail the notion that the learning continued for an unspecified time but the sentence is silent with respect to how long it continued, and silent with respect to whether it stopped at some point or whether he is still learning Italian."_ I'm OK with that! :) As long as it shows an incomplete process that took place in the past, starting at(from?) a specific moment and went on for(over?) some time. I explained it pretty well in my previous reply (just above the one with my suggested options with "study").

Comment: Just let me repeat that "Were you studying Italian from when you were a kid?" is not how a native speaker would ask the question. It is only marginally grammatical and some would say ungrammatical. The only time it could be asked is when there is another time in past, subsequent to the person's childhood. You are asking, in effect, something like this: When you entered university, had you been studing Italian ever since you were a child?  Only you're not choosing the past perfect tense, which would be grammatical, but past continuous, which is marginal at best.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice OK, I got it, thanks for the help. But still I'm trying to figure out what's the problem with that. 
Look, I've heard that the past continuous needs a certain time reference in the past, and I guess I have one in each of my sentences. They're "from the age of seven" and "from when you were a kid", aren't they enough as past references? If not, I could add "until in 1994 he decided to take up German" for the second sentence, would this help?

Comment: First, "from when you were a kid" in that context says "I am a non-native speaker".  Idiomatic alternatives include "since childhood" or "since you were a kid" or "since the age of seven" and a number of other possibilities. And if, by "since", you mean "up until now", the present moment, the time your question is spoken, you want to use the present perfect: "Have you been studying Italian since you were a kid?" But if you mean up until some point in time in the past, such as when the person entered university, it would be the past perfect: "Had you been studying Italian since childhood?"

Comment: Ran out of space: the present perfect continuous or the past perfect continuous. "Were you studying Italian since childhood when you entered university?" is not idiomatic. Ongoing action modified by "since" does comport well with a clause headed by **when** that refers to a point-in-time, not a time span.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice Now you've started answering someone else's questions, I'm afraid. That's not at all what I was asking. Please, reread my previous reply. First, as far as I understand "since" means from that point in time **until now,** but in all my examples I'm talking about actions that ceased a long time ago (just reread the main question and you'll see).

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice to put it simply, do you think *"My brother was learning Italian **from** the age of seven, **until** in 1994 he decided to take up German"* is a good sentence?

Comment: I would not consider that an "idiomatic" sentence though I would accept it as grammatical. "was learning ...from the age of 7" is the sticking point.  "My brother *started learning* [or *began to learn*] Italian at age 7 and continued with it until he took up German in his twenties."  (or however you want to specify the later time)

Comment: "from when" is not standard grammar.

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

"Did you start learning French when you were a kid?"

"My brother started learning Italian when he was seven."

Comment: Would you also say _"Have you started learning French since you were a kid?"_ and _"My brother has started learning Italian since he was seven"_ instead of these two _"Have you been learning French since you were a kid?"_ and _"My brother has been learning Italian since he was seven"_? **If not,** why wouldn't just use the past continuous _"Were you learning French from when you were a kid?"_ and _"My brother was learning Italian from the age of seven."_ ?

Comment: No, but this is an interesting question. "Have you started learning French?" is a correctly structured question, but it's really about the present state, not an event in the past. Other more common examples are "Have you started chemotherapy yet?" or, jokingly, "Have you started forgetting things in your old age?" Adding "...since you were a kid" somehow makes the sentence incorrect.